# Advice on photo app like InstaWeather (subviews on camera)

Tags: ios, xcode, swipe, uipagecontrol, gpuimage

On my iOS app I would add some scrolling subviews with location, weather, date, time like InstaWeather app for iOS.
I need to add these objects on the existing camera view and scrolling them with right/left swipe and a page control...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `cameraOverlayView` property of the `UIImagePickerController` [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

You can create your overlay camera view. Just set `yourPicker.showsCameraControls=NO`; and pass your view to your picker camera overlay view: `yourPicker.cameraOverlayView=yourView;`

Comment: But I'm using GPUImage framework and not UIImagePickerController

Comment: @user1763004 Then you have to specify that in your question or by using tags.